# AudioClip.Create() returns an AudioClip with no data

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When using AudioClip.Create() to create a new audio clip, Unity returns an AudioClip with no data. Samples, channels, length and frequency are all zero.

Here's the line of code I've used:

```cs
AudioClip audioClip = AudioClip.Create(fileName, f.Length, 1, 44100, false);
```

I've checked f.Length (which is a byte array), and the value is not zero, so it should create a clip with that length.After setting the data of the AudioClip with this line of code, it says the clip has no data:

```cs
audioClip.SetData(f, 0);

ERROR:
AudioClip.SetData failed; AudioClip  contains no data
```

Comment: Just to clarify, is `f` indeed a `byte` array or is it a `float` array? `SetData` requires a `float` array.

Comment: Same problem. It looks like a Unity bug. @Bones, did you find the way to solve the problem?

Comment: @Albeoris Yes, the project was using FMOD, which disables the base Unity Audio system. Turning it off solved the problem, but introduced some other bugs related to FMOD.

Comment: so... just don't use Unity things is the right way? I hate Unity.

Answer (score 0):

AudioClip::Create() which you had called in your script can create a wave or (wav) format data set on the memory which is initialized with all zero data .

What is f.Length in your create is only specifying that you have a dataset of sound in your memory which has length of (frequency / f.length -> Time in seconds) [in this case because you have only 1 channel (mono)].

So you have to use AudioClip::setData in order to fill the data of float[] in the memory in order to load it later using AudioSourceOBject.clip = audioclip and then after that you will be able to use AudioSourceOBject.Play() in order to play that piece of audioclip in your game.

Hope this help you to solve your problem!